# MVVM architecture - user rights and fetching data

Tags: entity-framework, mvvm

I am trying to figure out how to fit user rights and fetching data. This is not a simple task like

```
GetInvoices where Invoice.UserId = 5
```

so I can pass userId to a method, but it is much complex, and I do not want to go deeper than required, it cold create confusion. Currenly it work like this: View invokes a command on ViewModel, ViewMOdel calls repository method, that use EF to fetch the data. Now I need to filter this data based on user rights.

Logically, VIewModel should be forcing business rules.Does that mean that I should create IQueriable in the ViewModel, and pass it to the Model?

Or, it is ok to do

... if (LoggedUser.Role.Permissions.any(x=> x.PErmissionType == somePermission) && ....)

at the (M)odel side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **[DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer)** is the one that should fetch and filter the results based on the user's permissions. In other words, the VM should only receive the Model/Data that the user is allowed to see.
The VM enforces *business rules* as you said, but I'm not sure Model filtering fits into this category.

What you should do is when the VM requests data, he should pass whatever it is that is needed to filter the data based on permissions (either the userid, or the set of permissions that the user has), and only the data that fits his permissions should be returned.